# Question on the proof of Sard's theorem in John Lee's book.

Tags: differential-topology, smooth-manifolds

I tried to understand the proof of Sard's theorem suggested in John M. Lee’s “Introduction to Smooth Manifolds”.

It said that $C_k$ is defined as
$$
 C_k := \{x \in U  \vert \forall 1 \le i \le k\, \text{$i$-th partial derivatives of $f$ is $0$} \}
$$ for smooth function, $f : M \to N$, where $M, N$ is smooth manifold.

I've assumed that $i$-th partial derivatives denote each components of
$$
 \dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x^i}
$$ since Appendix C in same book follows this terminology.

However, when I read all parts of the proof, I'm strongly convinced that it means
$$
 \dfrac{\partial^i}{\partial x^I}f(\text{I is a sequence of indices, $|I| = i$})
$$, *i.e*, $i$-th order partial derivatives, rather than the above.

So, which one is correct? Is it just confusion in notations?

p.s.) Here is another question. If we accept $i$-th partial derivatives as $i$-th component partial derivates (rather than $i$-th order partial derivatives) in the proof, could we elaborate the proof of Sard's theorem in the case of $f \in C^\infty$ to the case of $f \in C^1$?

Comment: It seems more likely, and in agreement with the second interpretation, that $C_k$ denotes those function whose partial derivative up to order $k$ are zero. It would also be more similar to the notation for $C^k$ which usually stands for functions having continuous partial derivative up to order $k$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're right -- it should have said "$i$th-order partial derivatives." I've added this to my [online correction list](https://sites.math.washington.edu/~lee/Books/ISM/).